# CSS pseudo elements how to change the color

Tags: css

I'm not good at CSS. I'm a java script developer. I have found a code to add my project to add asterisk mark in the input fields.
This is the code. Can anybody tell me how to make this asterisk mark color red.

```
.required label::after {
  content: "*";
}
```

Comment: This way of indicating required fields isn't very accessible because pseudo content isn't content and will or will not be read out by screen readers, if yes in a certain manner that is probably unclear (and maybe not user friendly if the meaning of that asterisk isn't explained before the first field, like ["Fields marked with * are required"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/90685/using-asterisk-vs-required)). You can learn more with WCAG Techniques [Indicating required form controls using label or legend](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H90.html), G184, F81 and ARIA2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below CSS style

```
.required label::after {
  content: "*";
  color:#ff00ff;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Like any other element, you can add a color property to it.

```
.required label::after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}
```

Here's an example:

```css
.required label::after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="required">
  <label>Some text</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the `color` to set the color of the pseudo element as well.

```css
.required label:after {
  content: '*';
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class='required'>
  <label>First Name :</label>
  <input type ='text' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you perfectly

```
.required label::after {
   content: '*';
   width: 10px;
   color: blue;
}
```

Do provide width.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply add color property in your css class. Try below snippets

```
.required label::after {
content: '*';
color:#f00;
}
```

OR

```
.required label::after {
content: '*';
color:red;
}
```

OR

```
.required label::after {
content: '*';
color:rgb(255,0,0);
}
```